# How to select html cells and highlight by dragging like calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar

Assume we have tables like below.

If I mousedown at 2 then mouseup at 5,my desired result is cells 2,3,4,5 is highlighted like calendar view.

the other case is mousedown at 5 and then mouseup at 3, cells3,4,5 is highlitened.

How can I get such result? I tried by using toggle class but stacked now.

If someone has experienced such issues,please let me know.

[image]

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Please post your code that you have done yet

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. After [doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527), if you have a problem, please post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read ['How to Ask a good question' guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [Question Do's and Don'ts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527), and [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Done your problem, But after keep in mind that tell your problem more briefly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, but there is an use of `JQUERY`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var first;
  var second;
  var list = [];
  $("td").click(function(){   
    if(first == null){
      first = this.id;
    }else{
      second = this.id;
      for(var i = first;i <= second; i++){
        changecolor(i);
      }
    }
    
    
  });
  function changecolor(id){
    $("#"+id).css("background-color","yellow");

  }
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("td").each(function(){
      $(this).css("background-color","white");
      first = null;
      second = null;
    });
  });
});
```

```css
table tr td{
border:1px solid black;
padding:10px;
font-size:30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="1">1</td>
        <td id="2">2</td>
        <td id="3">3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="4">4</td>
        <td id="5">5</td>
        <td id="6">6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="7">7</td>
        <td id="8">8</td>
        <td id="9">9</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<button>Reset</button>
```